# How can I exit a 'for' loop in the main Arduino loop with a serial command?

Tags: arduino

I need to exit a 'for' loop running in the main loop on an Arduino board through a serial command, but it looks like that up to the end of the main loop the Serial Event is not taken in consideration. How can I solve this?

I supply some simplified code to have a better understanding of the problem:

```cpp
boolean start = false;
boolean abortLoop = false;
String inputString = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(start) {
    Serial.println("start");
    for(int i=0; i <10; i++) {
      if(abortLoop)
        break;
      Serial.println(i);
      delay(1000);
    }
    start = false;
    abortLoop = false;
  }
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    // Get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // Add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    //Serial.println(inputString);
    // If the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n')
    {
      inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length() - 1);
      //Serial.println(inputString);
      //Serial.println(inputString.length());
      if (inputString[0] == 's')
      {
        Serial.println("start");
        start = true;
      }
      if (inputString[0] == 'a')
      {
        abortLoop = true;
        Serial.println("abort");
      }
      inputString = "";
    }
  }
}
```

If sending the command 'a' in the middle of the loop, the loop keeps going up to the end.

The result is:

```
start
start
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
abort
abort
```

In this case, the 'a' command was sent two times.

Comment: serialEvent is in them main loop after loop(). it is not asynchronous to loop(). https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/24e6edd475c287cdafee0a4db2eb98927ce3cf58/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L45

Comment: Make a function call.  You cannot "exit" loop() except for calls that return and ISRs.  Try reading the documentation.

Comment: Yes you are right at the end the only way to read serial Event async is to use ISR..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. The only thing you have to do is to call your function in the *for* loop, else the function can't be executed.

```cpp
// ...

for(int i=0; i <10; i++) {
  serialEvent();
  if(abortLoop)
    break;
  Serial.println(i);
  delay(1000);
}

// ...
```

Moreover, I think it's better if you call your function at this place too:

```cpp
//  ...

void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if(start) {

  // ...
```

It's strangely not necessary, but in my opinion it's better. And 'start' is printed out two times, because you call it two times. One time here:

```cpp
void loop() {
  if(start) {
    Serial.println("start");
    for(int i=0; i <10; i++) {

and another time here:

if (inputString[0] == 'a')
{
  abortLoop = true;
  Serial.println("abort");
}
```

so you can remove one of them.

Comment: the loop() function and the serialEvent() function are called from an endless loop in main(). serialEvent only if input is available.

Comment: It looks like best choice will be to create a second loop..

Comment: to execute the code and in main check Serial Event.